# Handle array of string in edit form in Sonata Admin Bundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

In one of my entities, I got an **array** attribute. I thought Sonata Admin Bundle could handle it but it seems that it requires some attention.

I'm pretty sure `SONATA_TYPE_COLLECTION` field type could handle that but I didn't find any clue on how to configure the field in `configureFormFields()`

Do anyone know how to configure it ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try sonata_type_immutable_array ? http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/form_types_and_transformers.html

Comment: Check [this](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/forms/types/collection.html) type from symfony core

Answer (score 1):

I give you an example that I used:
Entity:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="array", nullable=true)
 */
private $tablaXY = [];
```

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\CollectionType;

```
->add('tablaXY',CollectionType::class, [
                    'required' => false,
                    'by_reference' => false, // Use this because of reasons
                    'allow_add' => true, // True if you want allow adding new entries to the collection
                    'allow_delete' => true, // True if you want to allow deleting entries
                    'prototype' => true, // True if you want to use a custom form type
                    'entry_type' => TablaType::class, // Form type for the Entity that is being attached to the object
                ],
                [
                    'edit' => 'inline',
                    'inline' => 'table',
                    'sortable' => 'position',
                ]
            )
```

form:

```
class TablaType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('ejeX',  TextType::class,['label' => 'Eje X (texto)',
            'required' => true,'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control'),])
            ->add('ejeY', NumberType::class,['label' => 'Eje Y (Número)',
            'required' => true])
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to that code - why do you think that it solves the problem? Keep in mind that the OP should be able to learn from your code, and not just copy and paste it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Sonata CollectionType class, which is capable of adding and removing elements from an array:

```
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\CollectionType;
...
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
        {
            $formMapper
                ->with('group')
                ->add('roles', CollectionType::class, array(
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                   ))
                ->end()
            ;
        }
```